# Magento 2 ui form multiselect field not checked not in $_POST

Tags: grid, magento2.2.2, ui-form, post-data

I have `multiselect`in my form displaying all store view available one is selected when I save only one show in the `post` array:

[image]

[image]

```
<field name="store">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Collection</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Is there anyway I can make all available options to go with `post` with the value of `0` ?

Comment: I think you need to pass all ids not only value 0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try passing all the **store ids** in your multiselect default value

```
<field name="store">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Collection</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1,2,3</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: I've already tried that but no luck.